# Defining Custom Invalid Feedback class

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap has an "invalid-feedback" class that warns users if they enter invalid input. For example, if the input field has type="email" then "invalid-feedback" will warn if the user enters something else than email.

So how can I set my custom condition on an invalid feedback class? Say for example I want to restrict the input with only a .jpeg image and if the user provides input data format of something else then it will throw a warning.

Comment: they explain this in the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#custom-styles

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must not use same class name as of core framework. Try some similar name e.g. `custom-invalid-feedback` and redesign the element in CSS file.

```
.custom-invalid-feedback{
    heigth : 200px;
    width : 200px;
    color : #333;
    //Do Else Stuff Here
}
```

Use this class name in required element and i suggest to use `!important` property only if required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how this will add a condition on which type of input gets accepted(As I asked in the question, for example, we want user can upload only .jpeg and if the user tries to upload something else then it should warn). I think your code will just change the style of the invalid-feedback class.

Answer (score 0):

with css alone you are limited. an example :

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}

input:optional {
  border-color: gray;
}

input:required {
  border-color: black;
}

input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Favorite pizza topping">
  <input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/gif" required/>
</form>
```

for more option is better to use something a little more complicated like JS or Sass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how this will add a condition on which type of input gets accepted(As I asked in the question, for example, we want user can upload only .jpeg and if the user tries to upload something else then it should warn). I think your code will just change the style of the invalid-feedback class.

Example 2:- In your last input of form, you have set attribute "accept"=image/gif", Now I want to set the condition on type of image format also. like "accept"=.jpeg

Comment: @Thunder as i said for more complicated validation you can use Js and etc, you can see how bootstrap do this in getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#custom-styles as mentioned in your comment by "ArleighHix"